# More than one level of function call in AsyncTask doInBackground() causes "Activity has leaked window" crash! Why?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a simple AsyncTask whose doInBackground() calls a function fn1 which in turn simply calls another fn2. The result is a "Activity has leaked window" crash! When I call fn2 directly from doInBackground() everything works fine. Does that mean in a thread one cannot have more than 1 level of fn calling?( Thread-> fn1->fn2)

I am new to Java and android, so please bear with me if that is a basic question! Thnx.

My code algo is something ike this :

**MyActivity:**

```
MyLibrary myLib;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myXML);

    myLib = new MyLibrary(MyActivity.this);
    new myTask().execute();

}

private class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", "Fetching Data...");
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            myLib.fn1();        
            return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**MyLibrary :**

```
Context ctx;
String iVar;

public MyLibrary(Context context){
    this.ctx = context;
}

public void fn1()
{

  fn2();
  Log.d("TAG", "Function 1";
}

public void fn2()
{
   iVar = "100"; 
   Log.d("TAG", "Function 2";
}
```

Comment: Try removing progressDialog.dismiss(); from OnPostExecute. That can sometimes cause nasty leaks.

Comment: Please post the stack trace. It would be interesting to know who actually throws this exception, instead of trying to guess what's going on and talking of mysterious leaks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following in your Activity's code:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if(progressDialog != null)
        progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

It will dismiss the dialog window in case you move away from activity.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error happens when the Activity that you're referencing already got removed from the top of the ActivityStack. You should really check if the AsyncTask got embedded correctly into your Activity's Lifecycle.

Best wishes,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

Somehow ProgressDialog may have got crashed during nested function call.